# How to export bundle items title?

Tags: magento-1.9, bundled-product, bundle

I have this script which gets all bundle products

```
$View = 2;

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                ->setStoreId($View)
                ->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('type')
                ->addFieldToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'bundle'))
                ;
```

Then I do this to cycle them and I try to get Store View Title (which is title)

```
foreach($products as $bundle)
{
        $productId = $bundle->getId();

        $bundled_product = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Product();      
        $bundled_product->load($productId);

        $typeInstance = $bundled_product->getTypeInstance(true);

        $selectionCollection = $typeInstance->getSelectionsCollection(
            $typeInstance->getOptionsIds($bundled_product), $bundled_product
        );

        $optionCollection = $typeInstance->getOptionsCollection($bundled_product);

        $_options = $optionCollection->appendSelections($selectionCollection, false, Mage::helper('catalog/product')->getSkipSaleableCheck());

        $bundle_option = array();

        foreach ($_options as $key => $value) 
        {
            echo $value->getData('title'); //Doesn't work, print nothing
            echo $value->getData('default_title'); //It Works
        }
}
```

However, despite I set the store_id to be what I want, it seems like it still takes the default view.

How can I print the Store View Title then?

Answer (score 0):

Change below code

```
$bundled_product = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Product();      
$bundled_product->load($productId);
```

To

```
$bundled_product = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Product();      
$bundled_product->setStoreId($storeId)->load($productId);
```

Comment: Thanks but it is still not working. It still prints an empty string

Comment: Please run indexing and flush cache and try again

Comment: I ran it but it won't work